# Memurai service doesn't start

Tags: redis, memurai

When I try to install `Memurai`, it tells me that I don't have the permission to start its service, Note that I'm Adminstartor user

[image]

And whn I try to start `Memurai` service manually, it give my this error

[image]

(Another note: I installed many applications/IDE/RDBMS with its services like SQLServer, Postgres.. without any problems)

So How I can fix this issue in my system??

Comment: Hi! Can you take a look at your System Logs and look for any 203 errors? There should be extra information there to help understand the problem. Can you share what you find, as long as it's not sensitive info. Also, what version of Windows are you running?

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I found this error message from **Event Viewer**: "The Memurai service terminated with the following error: 
The system could not find the environment option that was entered.". And Windows version is 19044.1889

Comment: Thanks for the info! As an administrator, can you try uninstalling and then re-installing the service as per https://docs.memurai.com/en/windows-service